# Pumpkin Spiced beer

Tags: beer

I was looking at your pumpkin beer recipe and I really want to brew that beer soon.  The recipe sounds great, I just want to know the exact boil times and what exact time to add the ingredients, spices etc.  I am new to this homebrewing.  Can you help out with this recipe?  Thank you

Nate

Comment: It would help if you posted the recipe.

Comment: Whose recipe?  Doesn't sound like much of a recipe if it doesn't have the details in it you are asking for.

Comment: http://brewadvice.com/questions/1659/spiced-pumpkin-recipe-any-hints-tips-or-tricks

Comment: I think he was talking about this recipe.

http://brewadvice.com/questions/1659/spiced-pumpkin-recipe-any-hints-tips-or-tricks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a 60 minute boil, so throw a half ounce of hops in as soon as it starts boiling.  After 45 minutes, throw in another half ounce of hops and the pumpkin, wait 15 minutes to make 60 minutes total boil, turn off heat and chill to fermentation temperature.  Pitch your yeast and let it sit in the primary for 5-7 days.  24 hours before you are going to transfer the beer to secondary, soak the spices in rum.  When you transfer the beer, pour the spices and rum through a coffee filter and add the filtered liquid to the beer.  Let it sit another 6 or 7 days and bottle or keg.